# Stop app from crashing when not selecting crop image app - Android

Tags: android

I have an app that crops an image either from the gallery or the camera. It works perfectly fine besides one small feature. When I select an image from the gallery it asks me what crop app I want to use in order to crop my image but if I click outside of the layout box or push the back button my entire app crashes. How can I get the app to not crash?

Here is my **Main Activity**

```
package com.goboapp;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

     ImageView imageView1;
     RoundImage roundedImage;
     Bitmap bitmap;
     ProgressDialog prgDialog;
     String encodedString;
     RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
     String imgPath, fileName;
     Bitmap bitmap2;
     TextView tv;
     String uploadFilePath;
     String uploadFileName;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //SET VIEWS
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        //CAMERA STUFF

        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);

                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        //END END END CAMERA STUFF


         }// End OnCreate



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }//end onCreateOptionsMenu

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }//end onOptionsItemSelected



    //CAMERA STUFF

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                   imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo);


                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;

        }
    }



    //CROP IMAGE

      private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
          intent.setType("image/*");

          List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

          int size = list.size();

          if (size == 0) {          
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              return;
          } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

              intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
              intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
              intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
              intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
              intent.putExtra("scale", true);
              intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
          }
    }

      //END END END CROP IMAGE





}//end activity
```

This is **CropOptionAdapter.java**

```
package com.goboapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is **CropOption.java**

```
package com.goboapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

This is the **crop_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the **LogCat**

```
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829): Process: com.goboapp, PID: 23829
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/1448 from pid=23829, uid=10168 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:536)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1282)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.goboapp.Main$5.onCancel(Main.java:340)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1241)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-17 20:17:15.708: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have omitted some functions from my **Main** activity that were irrelevant. I am also wondering if it is possible to force the user to use the default crop app instead of asking them to choose. I followed a tutorial to get this code that is why I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is missing the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I assume whatever is cropping the photo requires being able to write to the disk, because it is using the `MediaProvider` content provider.